# How can I get a SUM of the items in my grouped query?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a list of postcodes in a query (ThisInstructorsPostcodes) and another query that pulls back sales referrals (LastWeeksReferrals)

I am using the below syntax to perform the linq equivalent of LEFT OUTER JOIN so I always get a postcode back, even if there were no referrals for it.

```
        dim final = from tip in ThisInstructorsPostcodes _
        group join lwr in LastWeeksReferrals on tip.PostcodeID equals lwr.PostcodeID Into lwrgrp = group _
        from lwrgrpq in lwrgrp.DefaultIfEmpty _
        select new with {tip.AreaDistrict, lwrgrpq }

    final.dump()
```

The results I am getting are *so* close to what I need, but I am getting a bunch of InstructorReferrals objects in the lwrgrpq column and what I want to do is simple sum of the all the 'Referrals' integers in those InstructorReferrals objects.

[image: Results in LinqPad]

I thought this would work:

```
        dim final = from tip in ThisInstructorsPostcodes _
        group join lwr in LastWeeksReferrals on tip.PostcodeID equals lwr.PostcodeID Into lwrgrp = group _
        from lwrgrpq in lwrgrp.DefaultIfEmpty _
        select new with {tip.AreaDistrict, lwrgrpq.Sum(function(x) x.Referrals) }
```

...but it doesn't - fails with the error:

> Anonymous type member name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments.

I'm struggling because I have only used this linq query structure in order to mimic the outer join behaviour of sql, does anyone know how I can fix this so that my grouped items are not anonymous types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar to VB.NET but you are getting the error because you didn't set property names in anonymous type. Try this in select clause:

```
select new with { 
                    .AreaDistrict= tip.AreaDistrict,
                    .ReferralSum =lwrgrpq.Sum(function(x) x.Referrals) 
                }
```